# Create 2 Post Types, one parent to another in Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a custom post type "Book", and successfully added to WordPress' admin menu as a root category. I can successfully list the post type contents with `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=test_book` & can add via `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=test_book`.

However, I would like to add a custom post type "Chapter" (`test_chapter`) to "Book", by allowing users to choose chapters (and re-arrange the order in `post-new.php`), thus establishing the parent-child relationship.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you need to use here has some steps. First you need to create e metabox on your custom post type edit.php which will list all your posts of test_chapter post type. Then you have to hook the save_post action so you set the parent of your edited post to the chosen "test_chapter". The best way is to connect these two post types as post meta and not as parent-child relation so you can handle it better. According to this tutorial: http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_books_metaboxes' );
    // Add the Book Meta Boxes

    function add_books_metaboxes() {
        add_meta_box('wpt_test_chapter', 'Book chapter', 'wpt_test_chapter', 'test_book', 'side', 'default');
    }


// Book chapter Metabox

function wpt_test_chapter() {
    global $post;


    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'test_chapter',
    );
    $books_array = get_posts( $args );
    $chapter_ids = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_chapters', true);
    ?>
    <select name="book_chapters" multiple>
    <?php
    foreach($books_array as $book_array){
        if(in_array($book_array->ID, $chapter_ids)){$selected = 'selected;'}
        else{$selected = '';}
        echo '<option '.$book_array->ID.' '.$selected.'>'.$book_array->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    /* if you are using plugin:
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
    */
}



// Save the Metabox Data

function wpt_save_chapter_meta($post_id, $post) {

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    /* if you are using plugin:
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }
    */
    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

    $chapters_ids['book_chapters'] = $_POST['book_chapters'];

    // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

    foreach ($chapter_ids as $chapter_id) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
        //if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_chapters', $chapter_id);
    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_chapter_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```

Have not tested the code so it may have some mistakes. Let me knwo so I can correct them.

Answer (score -2):

First you create test_book function and call `add_action()` function to initialize this function.

Example:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_book');
```

Then after you define test_book() function functionality, for adding menu and sub-menu you declare your `function test_book()` like this manner....

```
function test_book(){
    add_menu_page( "Books", "Books", "manage_options", "test_book", "test_book", "" );
    add_submenu_page( "test_book", "Chapters", "Chapters", "manage_options", "test_chapter", "test_chapter");
}
```

Comment: But this does not connect the relationship between Book & Chapter CPT.

Comment: Books is primary/parent menu and Chapters is submenu of books

Comment: I'm not talking about menu hierarchy. As mentioned in question, I would like to select chapters when I'm adding / editing book.

Comment: global $wpdb;
 $data = $wpdb->get_results("select * from `wp_chapter` where 1=1");
 $optionchapter = "<select name='auditChapter' id='auditChapter' onchange='getBook(this.value)'>";
 if(count($data)>0){
  $optionchapter = "<option value=''>--Select Chapter--</option>";
  foreach($data as $key => $val){
   $optionchapter .= "<option value='".trim($data[$key]->chapter_id)."'>".trim(strtoupper($data[$key]->chapter_name))."</option>";
  }
 }
 else{
  $optionchapter .= "<option value=''>--Select Chapter--</option>";
 }
 $optionchapter = "</select>"; echo $optionchapter;

Comment: Where should I put this piece of code? Can you edit your answer and put the codes inside? Hard to read codes in comment. Thanks.